# How to send a dictionary using AJAX GET method in django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, dictionary

I need to send a dictionary(*its length is 31*) and need to get the dictionary in Django.

Jquery:

```
$('#shift_save').click(function(){
    $("#usershift tr").each(function(){
      usershift={};
      var userid = $(this).attr('id');
      usershift['shiftmember'] = userid;
      $("#usershift tr#" +userid+" td").each(function(){
      var shiftname = $(this).text();
      var shiftday = $(this).attr('id');
      usershift[shiftday] = shiftname;
      });
      var currenturl = window.location.href;
      currenturl = currenturl.split("/");
      year = currenturl[5];
      month = currenturl[6];
      url = "/roster/saveshift/"+year+"/"+month;
      $.get(url, {my_user_shift: usershift}, function(data){
            Materialize.toast(data['status'], 8000, 'rounded');
       });
    })
 })
```

Views.py:

```
def save_mass_shift(request,year,month):
try:
    data_json = {}
    user_shift = request.GET['my_user_shift']
    save_user_shift(user_shift,month,year)
    data_json['status'] = 'Saved successfully'
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data_json),content_type="application/json")
except Exception as e:
    data_json['status'] = str(e)
    print(str(e))
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data_json),content_type="application/json")
```

Error:

Just showing the jquery dictionary name as error

date dict looks like :

```
samlple = {"a":'navi',"b":'vbn'}
```

Comment: What does "showing the jquery dictionary name as error" mean? Where are you getting the error - in js or Django? What is the **full*" error message?

Answer (score 0):

ajax method have the get request, you can send data using that method.

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "test.html",
     method: "GET",
     data:{}
}).done(function() {
 // do your operations
});
```

in django you can access using

```
 request.GET
```

Comment: yes i have tried this but still i could not get the jquery dictionary